# Sitecore10 MVC AuthorizationFilterAttribute OnAuthorization method is not firing

Tags: authentication, sitecore, pipeline, action-filter, custom-action-filter

Authorization filter attribute is not firing

```
 public class AuthenticationRequiredAttribute : System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute
    {
        public override bool AllowMultiple
        {
            get { return false; }
        }
        
        public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {            
            base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);
           
        }
```

I have decorated controller with the attribute

```
 [AuthenticationRequired]
    public class ProfileController : BaseController
    {        
        public ProfileController(IMyRepository repository)
            : base(repository)
        {
        }
    }
```

The  *AuthenticationRequired* filter is not firing, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using a Web API filter instead of an MVC filter.
Inherit your custom authorization filter from  `System.Web.Mvc.FilterAttribute` class and `System.Web.Mvc.IAuthorizationFilter` interface, and implement `OnAuthorization()` method.

For example,

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Sitecore;


namespace {YOUR_PROJECT_NAMESPACE}
{
    public class AuthenticationRequired : System.Web.Mvc.FilterAttribute, System.Web.Mvc.IAuthorizationFilter
    {
        public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            {YOUR_CUSTOM_CODE_LOGIC}
        }
    }

}
```

You can configure your custom filter in your application at three levels:

- **Global level** by registering your filter in `Application_Start` event of `Global.asax.cs`;
- **Controller level** by decorating a controller with your filter by putting your filter at the top of the controller name;
- **Action level** by decorating a given action method with your filter in a similar way as above for controllers.

In your case you simply need to decorate your controller with your custom filter.

Hope this helps.